# Weavy not rendering correctly in a Vue app

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I see a react library for Weavy but not a Vue library. There is a plain js library so I'm attempting to use that.  I think I have it almost working, I'm just having trouble getting it to render. I have:

```js
  const posts = ref(undefined);
  const weavyUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_WEAVY_URL;

  Weavy.url = weavyUrl;
  Weavy.tokenFactory = async (refresh) => {
    // fetch access_token for the authenticated user with an api call to your application backend
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3002/token?&refresh=${refresh}`);
    const token = await response.text();

    return token.access_token;
  };

  posts.value = new Posts({ uid: 'demofeeds' });
```

And in the template I have:

```html
  <div id="feeds-container" style="height: 600px">{{ posts }}</div>
```

But what gets rendered is:

"[object HTMLElement]"

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `new Posts({ uid: 'demofeeds' });` returns an `Object` - now, recall in javascript 101 that most object `toString` method won't return a usable string of data, e.g. `({}.toString())` - so, you need to what `new Posts` is to know how to use it